# Parse JS SDK Login into Parse Server running in Node.JS = fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

fellow developers.

I'm migrating an app that was using Parse Hosted and the new code will run *inside Node.JS (with express)*. I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out a problem, though: **my JavaScript SDK requests always return "Cannot GET /parse/1/login"**, as if I was requesting an invalid express route. I know it is valid because if I reproduce the call without the right appID it will return the `{"error":"unauthorized"}` message.

I'm trying the **most basic possible version**, using Node.JS code from the [Parse docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server--express):

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Connection string for your MongoDB database
  cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey: 'myMasterKey', // Keep this key secret!
  fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

app.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

The Node.JS server runs OK and **I can even query data using cURL requests** with no problems at all.

My login code is also the most basic possible version, running directly into the browser console in a page that loads the JS SDK:

```
Parse.User.logIn("user", "pass", {
  success: function(user) {
    console.log('ok', user);
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    console.log('error', user, error);
  }
});
```

The return is simply `Cannot GET /parse/1/login` (it seems to come from Express, but **the message changes if I remove the appID**, so I know the Parse Server is getting it). It is worth noting that this very same call worked perfectly if I issue it against *api.parse.com* servers: `{"code":101,"error":"invalid login parameters"}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, guys, I just found out that the **problem was the JS SDK Version**. Really begginer's mistake, but I just couldn't imagine that it would require changes in the SDK since the new Parse Server should be compatible with the Hosted version.

For the record, **I was at JS SDK version 1.6.7** and I **updated to the 1.6.14** and it works just fine now.